# Change the UI at run time using C++ only ( No QML )

Tags: qt, blackberry-10

I have screen 1 on which there is a SUBMIT button. On click of the submit button I want to load another screen 2. the UI of screen 2 is developed using only Qt C++. there is no QML document related to that.

On the click of the submit button I have called a function `void DoSubmit()`. In this function I have made a page object.

```
Page * PageObj = new Page();
```

In this `PageObj` I have added containers and other controls and constructed my UI for scene 2, now I try to set this page as my current scene using the following command:

```
Application :: instance()->setScene( PageObj );
```

by doing so my app getting crashed but when I remove the statement containing `Application :: instance()->setScene( PageObj )` it does not crash.

What is the problem in this I am not able to figure out. Please help..

Comment: I'm not sure what blackberry development is like.  But when you get this crash do you have any kind of stack trace you can edit your question to provide?  ("It crashed" is somewhat generic, and could be anything...)  It also helps if you reduce your situation for troubleshooting.  If you put *just one control that does nothing* in the page, does it still crash...?

Answer (score 1):

The scene should not be used for adding a page, just the first one. You would better use a navigationPane or a sheet.

See the doc:
https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/navigation/index.html